# Good book for self study of Continued Fractions

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation, continued-fractions

Does anyone have a recommendation for a rigorous while readable book to use for the self study of continued fractions?

---

PS - As examples of "rigorous while readable book" for self-learning, A. Pressley's book on Differential Geometry and P. Fitzpatrick's book on Advanced Calculus are much better than the other books of same subjects.

Comment: I don't know if Continued Fractions with Applications
LORENTZEN, L.; WAADELAND, H. is good at all?

Answer (score 3):

I would start with  Khinchin's *Continued Fractions* . For $8.95 you can't go wrong, and you can move on to something more advanced when you're done.

http://store.doverpublications.com/0486696308.html

Comment: I second this, Khinchin is a great introduction.

Comment: In Ch.3, is "the measure theory" the same as the measure theory studied in advanced analysis? If so, then it must be so hard...

Comment: @Edi Yes, that's the measure theory from advanced analysis, and you need the definitions after the first few pages. But Chapters 1 and 2 are elementary (no advanced course work required). You can see the style at google books.

Comment: @Edi: The third chapter requires more background, but the first two are elementary. The presentation is clear but rather concise, and there’s little if anything that you can afford to skip. It’s definitely a book to be read with pen and paper handy. There are undoubtedly gentler introductions out there, but this is a very good one, well worth the price.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Looking at contents and first pages, it looks that Neverending Fractions by Poorten .. should be the best choice for me, but I can't find a free or cheap ebook of it. Could you please send me if you a pdf of it? Thanks

Comment: @Edi: I don’t know that one at all, I’m afraid.